# postgres makes db dump without password

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

if i write on console at home (new machine, random IP):

```
/usr/bin/pg_dump --host xxxxxx --port xxxxxx --username "yyyy"
--no-password  --format plain --create --clean --section pre-data --section data --section post-data --inserts --column-inserts --verbose --file "/POSTGRES/backup_2016-09-08" "bbbbb"
```

serwer dumps database without asking for password! how do i block it?

my pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    aaaa              all             0/0                     md5
host    bbbb      all             0/0                     md5
```

Answer (score 4):

ops, how stupid I am...

i have used 1 time pgadmin and logged to my  external postgress server
it made in my home directory **.pgpass** file

if i delete it - pg_dump doesn't work without password

my error!

Comment: Good on you for posting an answer rather than doing what too many people do and deleting the post. It's so annoying when you're answering someone's question and when you go to post it says they've deleted it. So thanks.